# Ubuntu 20.04.1 logsout every time I try to start terminal

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

I have a strange behavior that terminal window is killing X server every time I try to open terminal window. After logging out I can't login anymore, I need to restart any recommendations?

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in `.profile` or `.bashrc`?

Comment: OMG it was that! THANKS @Jos, very strange :/ I though it has something to do with drivers or some bug, I had .bashrc and .profile files on /home partition from previous 16.04 ubuntu distribution, so It actually made kill X server :/